# How to check validity a few required field of a form in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form named "myForm" and I have a lot of required fields.

```
<input type="text" name="form.user.name" ng-model="form.user.name" required/>
<input type="text" name="form.user.email" ng-model="form.user.email" required/>
<input type="text" name="form.user.phone" ng-model="form.user.phone" required/>

<input type="text" name="form.user.accountNumber" ng-model="form.bank.accountNumber" required/>
<input type="text" name="form.user.accountName" ng-model="form.bank.accountName" required/>
```

Now I just want to check validity of only `form.user` information. How can I do this?

Comment: check where? In html or in controller? What is name on form? Need that to access validation object

Comment: I read question twice,still not clear what you want.

Comment: I want to check it in HTML. If user fileds are filled up then "next" button will be enable and after click next a tab will be open with bank info fields.

Comment: Best place to start would be study an angular form validation tutorial

Answer (score 2):

Go through this link first
https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms

**Example of custom validation**

```
<form name="form" class="css-form" novalidate>
  <div>
    <label>
    Size (integer 0 - 10):
    <input type="number" ng-model="size" name="size"
           min="0" max="10" integer />{{size}}</label><br />
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer">The value is not a valid integer!</span>
    <span ng-show="form.size.$error.min || form.size.$error.max">
      The value must be in range 0 to 10!</span>
  </div>

</form>
```

In the below line in `ng-show`, `form` is form name, `size` is input field name, `$error` is default object to store failed validators. `integer` is a directive to do the validation of input field.

```
<span ng-show="form.size.$error.integer">The value is not a valid integer!</span>
```

**script**

```
var app = angular.module('form-example1', []);

var INTEGER_REGEXP = /^-?\d+$/;
app.directive('integer', function() {
  return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
      ctrl.$validators.integer = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
        if (ctrl.$isEmpty(modelValue)) {
          // consider empty models to be valid
          return true;
        }

        if (INTEGER_REGEXP.test(viewValue)) {
          // it is valid
          return true;
        }

        // it is invalid
        return false;
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just try..

When you put `<form>` tag inside you ngApp, AngularJS automatically adds form controller (actually there is a directive, called `form` that add nessesary behaviour).

So to check form validity, you can check value of `$scope.yourformname.$valid` property of scope.

Each input `name`'s validation information is exposed as property in `form`'s name in scope.

HTML

```
<form name="someForm" action="/">
    <input name="username" required />
    <input name="password" type="password" required />
</form>
```

JS

```
$scope.someForm.username.$valid
// > false
$scope.someForm.password.$error
// > { required: true }
```

More information you can get at Developer's [Guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) section about forms.

Answer (score 0):

Refer angular Validation https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms
Give different name. you are given same name last three input types.

```
   <input type="text" name="form.user.name" ng-model="form.user.name" required/>
<input type="text" name="form.user.email" ng-model="form.user.email" required/>
<input type="text" name="form.user.phone" ng-model="form.user.phone" required/> // same name all three name="form.user.phone"

<input type="text" name="form.user.phone" ng-model="form.bank.accountNumber" required/> // same name all three name="form.user.phone"
<input type="text" name="form.user.phone" ng-model="form.bank.accountName" required/> // same name all three name="form.user.phone"
```